# How to retain jar dependencies after obfuscating with ProGuard

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation, proguard

I have a collection of jar files with dependencies in a diamond pattern:

> base.jar
>            /          \
>   dep1.jar     dep2.jar
>            \          /
>            dep3.jar

I would like to obfuscate them with ProGuard to retain their dependencies, so that, for example, the obfuscated versions of base.jar and dep2.jar can execute in isolation, without the obfuscated versions of dep1.jar and dep3.jar (just as they can, unobfuscated). There are classes distributed among the jars with the same package names, and methods in the dependent jars that call methods (in various classes) *that I want to be obfuscated*, in the jars they depend on.

When I try to obfuscate all the jars at once, ProGuard doesn't "understand" their dependencies; and takes a static method from a class in base.jar and moves it to an obfuscated class in dep1.jar. Code in the obfuscated version of dep2.jar that "expects" that method in base.jar, fails at runtime if dep1.jar is not on the classpath.

**How can I insure the dependencies in the obfuscated jars is retained?**

The documentation suggests using an [incremental obfuscation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#incremental) but the `-applymapping` switch it seems to require can only take *one* argument telling the dependent methods the obfuscated names to use in calling into *the jars they depend on*, that get obfuscated first. The obfuscation of dep1.jar can produce one such mapping file argument, and that of dep2.jar can produce another but the obfuscation of dep3.jar needs *both* of those mapping files (plus that of base.jar?) in its `-applymapping` argument. dep1.jar and dep2.jar cannot be obfuscated together (*or can they?*), however, to produce a single mapping file, because code might be relocated from one to the other. **Must I merge the mapping files myself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (albeit sub-optimal) solution is to process them all at once, without optimization (-dontoptimize).

Answer (score 1):

We've used ProGuard for two or three years now, without the `-repackageclasses` flag in our config, and our .jar files come out obfuscated and still behave properly.  Anyone poking around inside our .jar files can see that our namespace is com.[company] , which is something that flag can hide, but we decided that wasn't really a big deal.  You should be okay without it.

(as an aside, I wonder if your class names are being obfuscated before `-repackageclasses` takes effect, and there's a name collision somewhere?  We had a problem similar to that once.)

Comment: I've restated my question since you answered, so people might not understand that you responded to my original concern, since disproved (by me), that the `-repackageclasses` argument caused the change in obfuscation dependencies.