# Providing plugin API for obfuscated jar application

Tags: java, api, jar, dependencies, obfuscation

How would I go about providing a separate jar file containing a plugin API for an closed source application distributed as an obfuscated jar file?

The application would be using the API internally for some functionality.

In a sense I've managed to achieve this, utility classes that would be needed by some plugins are put in the jar containing the plugin API, and this is then also used by the main application classes internally.

The problems arise when I encounter a class that would be needed by both, but the certain access should be limited to the main application.

As an example I've got an EventManager class like so:

```
public final class EventManager {
    // Put an event on the queue, needed by plugins.
    public void pushEvent(Event event) { ... }        

    // Register listeners for particular events, needed by plugins.
    public void registerListener(EventListener listener) { ... }

    // This method should not be visible to the plugin designers!
    // The application should have rigid control over when this is called.
    public void processEvents() { ... }
}
```

Perhaps the issue can be solved through a different design that I've not considered, or the idea is flawed, this is my first attempt to create an extensible application.

If the application was to be distributed as a single package I could use package visibility for classes and put such details there, but since I want the application itself to be closed off I see no way for the plugin API and the application to reside in the same jar.

I've spent a good couple of hours trying to research this, and most resources treat the various topics involved in this problem individually, but not how to combine them, or they're not exactly related. Here are a few links that kept comming up:

- [Obfuscate dependencies to single jar with Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045474/obfuscate-dependencies-to-single-jar-with-proguard) (I want my files separated, and only one of them obfuscated).
- http://theamiableapi.com/java-cl-section-1-1/#cl.item.1.1.4 (Separating API and implementation into different archives, does not deal with one of them being obfuscated, great article through).
- [How to retain jar dependencies after obfuscating with ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902538/how-to-retain-jar-dependencies-after-obfuscating-with-proguard) (Closer, but here all the archives are still being obfuscated).

**Question summary:** How to provide an extension/plugin API for an obfuscated application as a separate jar file?

This is my first question on SO so hopefully I've not broken too many rules.

Comment: What is the reason the API jar must be obfuscated?

Comment: The API jar should not be obfuscated, the API is meant to be useful to anyone who wishes to write extensions. The main application (for which the extensions are written), should be obfuscated though. If there appears to be more confusion about this I'll try to clarify the question better.

Comment: I believe the consensus was that your cannot avoid piracy with obfuscation in Java. You can use the license and calling back to a mothership to do stuff instead.

Comment: Its not purely to make piracy harder, its a way to say "modify this, but not this" I suppose. I don't understand the last sentence, could you clarify?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with providing a "foo-api.jar" along with "foo.jar" and friends, instead of going for obfuscation (where it is unclear to me if this is a customer requirement or you are just investigating on your own).  Regarding the mothership: If you make your application depend on being able to reach back to your servers to do some important calculation needed for further processing, you can provide that only to those with a valid license-

Comment: Ah, there is no customer requirement to use obfuscation, its just something I'm looking into. Yes ultimatly to protect against piracy some form of online verification would be necessary. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: In that case I suggest you look a bit into the various questions about protecting java programs against reverse engineering. It might save you some research time.